# ¿Cómo hacer un Progress Loading o animación de actualización durante una petición axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-axios

¿cómo puedo crear un círculo de carga, por ejemplo, cuando hago una petición XmlHtpp con Axios en mi vista con ReactJS?

Actualmente logro eso con la etiqueta `<Get/>` de la dependencia `react-axios`.

> **Ojo**: react-axios no es axios. React Axios tiene COMPONENTES con etiquetas Get, Put, etc. Más información: [react-axios - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-axios)

Con el component `<Get/>` logro algo que me gusta mucho y es que puedo poner un **Progress Loading**, fijense en lo siguiente:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Get url="/api/user" params={{id: "12345"}}>
        {(error, response, isLoading, makeRequest, axios) => {
          if(error) {
            return (<div>Something bad happened: {error.message} <button onClick={() => makeRequest({ params: { reload: true } })}>Retry</button></div>)
          }
          else if(isLoading) {
            return (<div>Loading...</div>)
          }
          else if(response !== null) {
            return (<div>{response.data.message} <button onClick={() => makeRequest({ params: { refresh: true } })}>Refresh</button></div>)
          }
          return (<div>Default message before request is made.</div>)
        }}
      </Get>
    </div>
  )
}
```

En la condición `if(isLoading)` perfectamente puedo colocar un componente de animación, por ejemplo, el `<CircularProgress/>` de **MaterialUI**. Esto funciona muy bien... Pero la lógica que necesito no me permite usar la etiqueta para peticiones con react-axios `<Get/>`.

Por esa razón, quisiera saber cómo o dónde poner un "Loading" durante una petición con Axios... Por ejemplo, si tuviera esto:

```
async function getUser() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/user?ID=12345');
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

¿Dónde coloco mi `<div>Loading...</div>` mientras espero la respuesta o dónde manipulo una variable booleana para activarlo en el render? Que la variable se mantenga en false mientras espero la respuesta y cambie a true cuando recibe respuesta y ahí detengo la vista de que está cargando...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar `this.setState` para manipular el estado del componente cuando estas esperando la petición y cuando finaliza

```
async function getUser() {
  try {
    this.setState({isLoading: true})
    const response = await axios.get('/user?ID=12345');
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  finally{
    this.setState({isLoading: false})
  }
}
```

usar finally para que el loading desaparezca aunque la petición resulte exitosa o falle

Comment: Ya lo había resuelto prácticamente de la misma forma, gracias por responder. No tuve que escribir la respuesta, jeje.